# NSDateFormatter dateFromString fails for unseen reason

Tags: ios7, xcode6, nsdateformatter

[image: dateFromString returns nil - runtime breakpoint]

(runtime breakpoint) I try to  change the time format (input string: dateFromSettings), but dateFromString fails & date gets nil. I can't figure-out why.

Comment: `d` => `dd` in your dateformat?

Comment: If you're using [this script](http://code.wrightscs.com/?p=152) then fix it by calling `$(date +dd:mm:yy)` (or whatever) so that the date is easier to parse.  Is `CFBuildDate` an official `info.plist` entry?  If not it should not start with `CF`. Also, if you're using that script then it's broken as you should not mess with `info.plist` during a build; instead use a dependent  *External Build System* target.

Comment: Droppy, thanks. When I change the $(date) in the script to:
CFBuildDate=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M")
and I change in the code above to:
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"]; the parsing does not fail.